# Joining disjointed arrays into one array

Tags: javascript

I have a map that returns a disjointed list of arrays.

```
(3) ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
(1) ["string4"]
(2) ["string5", "string6"]
```

How can I get

```
(6) ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"]
```

I've tried concat(), Set(), Map(). but cant wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const strings = [["string1", "string2", "string3"], ["string4"],["string5", "string6"]]
console.log(strings.flat())
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) like so:

```
let flattenedArray = arrayOfArrays.flat();
```

```js
let arr = [
  ["string1", "string2", "string3"],
  ["string4"],
  ["string5", "string6"]
];

let result = arr.flat();

console.log(result);
```

**Note:** if the array of arrays is the result of a `map`, you can do both (mapping and flattening) in one step by using [`Array.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead like so:

```
let flattenedArray = originalArray.flatMap( /* callback that returns subarrays */ );
```

```js
let arr = [
  "string1-string2-string3",
  "string4",
  "string5-string6"
];

let result = arr.flatMap(str => str.split("-"));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for looking into this, however in your second example my arrays are not joined by dashes so its solving another problem unfortunately.

Comment: @umbriel that was just a demo to show you how `flatMap` works, the callback can be anything that returns arrays, I just used `split` for demonstration. Just replace `map` with `flatMap` in your code and it will work